Realizo doble autentificacion en laravel para eso uso google2fa, tengo error con la verificacion del codigo que ingresan
Me estaba guiando aqui https://styde.net/autenticacion-de-dos-factores-con-laravel/ pero pese a eso tengo el error que menciono mas abajo
Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi LoginController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\ImageRenderer;
use BaconQrCode\Writer as BaconQrCodeWriter;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\ImagickImageBackEnd;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\RendererStyle\RendererStyle;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.signin');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $rememberMe = $request->rememberMe ? true : false;

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user && Auth::attempt($credentials, $rememberMe)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            if ($user->two_factor_enabled) {
                $user->update(['token_login' => (new Google2FA)->generateSecretKey()]);

                $urlQR = $this->createUserUrlQR($user);

                return view('auth.2fa', compact('urlQR', 'user'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
            }
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Las Credenciales ingresadas son incorrectas.',
        ])->withInput($request->only('email'));
    }

    public function createUserUrlQR($user)
    {
        $bacon = new BaconQrCodeWriter(new ImageRenderer(
            new RendererStyle(200),
            new ImagickImageBackEnd()
        ));

        $data = $bacon->writeString(
            (new Google2FA)->getQRCodeUrl(
                config('app.name'),
                $user->email,
                $user->token_login
            ), 'utf-8'
        );

        return 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    }

    public function login2FA(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $request->validate(['code_verification' => 'required']);

    // Verificar los valores recibidos
    logger()->info('User token_login:', ['token_login' => $user->token_login]);
    logger()->info('User entered code:', ['code_verification' => $request->code_verification]);

    $google2fa = new Google2FA();
    $isValid = $google2fa->verifyKey($user->token_login, $request->code_verification);

    // Verificar el resultado de la verificación
    logger()->info('2FA verification result:', ['isValid' => $isValid]);

   

    if ($isValid) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'Código de verificación incorrecto']);
}

    
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/sign-in');
    }
}

y el siguiente en mi 2fa.blade.php
<x-guest-layout>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login 2FA') }}</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            @if ($errors->has('error'))
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $errors->first('error') }}
              </div>
            @endif

            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login.2fa', $user->id) }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
              @csrf
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <img id="imgQR" src="{{ $urlQR }}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="code_verification" class="col-form-label">
                      {{ __('CÓDIGO DE VERIFICACIÓN') }}
                    </label>
                    <input 
                      id="code_verification" 
                      type="text" 
                      class="form-control @error('code_verification') is-invalid @enderror" 
                      name="code_verification"
                      value="{{ old('code_verification') }}" 
                      required
                      autofocus>
                    @error('code_verification')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                      </span>
                    @enderror
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</x-guest-layout>

MI ERROR ES QUE AL INGRESAR UN CODIGO SEA VALIDO O NO ME MANDA A MI DASHBOARD Y NO DEBERIA SIESQUE ESTA MAL, EL TOKEN SI SE GUARDA EN LA BASE DE DATOS Y TAMBIEN SE VERIFICA BIEN YA LO COMPROBE VIENDO LOS LOG Y SI ME SALE FALSE SIESQUE INGRESO MAL Y TRUE SI INGRESO BIEN EL CODIGO PERO NO ENTIENDO PORQUE NO ME DA EL MENSAJE DE ERROR SI INGRESO MAL Y AUN ASI MANDA A MI DASHBOARD
